# Trouble with UIPickerView Outlets in iOS5?

Tags: delegates, ios5, datasource, xcode4.2, uipickerview

I don't understand which outlets should be connected!
In outlets i have:

`dataSource`
`delegate`

But where should i connect them?
And how can i then use them?

???

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, connect the datasource & delegate outlets to the UIViewController that contains the UIPickerView. The **datasource methods** are declared in the UIViewController implementation. Let's say your picker will display: "English" and "French":

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSArray *pickerContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"English", @"French", nil];
    return [pickerContent objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

The **delegate methods** are also declared in the UIViewController implementation:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSArray *titles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"English", @"French", nil];
    NSString *userSelectionFromPicker = [titles objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Some examples of how `userSelectionFromPicker` can be used to perform an action in the app:

1. A View Controller method: `[localMethod doSomethingWith:userSelectionFromPicker]`
2. NB: `userSelectionFromPicker` is made a property of the View Controller (as opposed to a local variable) and accessed by the View Controller's delegate - often when the View Controller is dismissed
3. A notification is invoked when `userSelectionFromPicker` changes

Comment: How can I make it do something (action) when I select English and French?

Comment: How can I make it do something (action) when I select English and French?